# d3.js substitute d3.csv to work with array

Tags: d3.js

I am learning D3.

I have worked through a nice graph example below which uses a CSV file. It takes data from month and sales column in the CSV file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>

<style>
</style>
</head>
<title>
</title>
<body>
    <div id="myDiv"></div>
</body>
<script>
//Sales Data
d3.csv("sales.csv").then(function(data){
    console.log(data);



//Values for bar chart
var height = 300;
var width = 600;
var dataCount = data.length;
var gap = 2;


//Convert to numbers


data.forEach(function(d){
    d.sales = Number(d.sales); // sales from sales csv
})


//Create a scale for Y
var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0,d3.max(data, function(d){
        return d.sales; // sales from sales csv
        })])
    .range([height, 0]);

//Create a scale for X
var xScale = d3.scaleBand()
    .domain(data.map(function(d){
        return d.month; // return month from sales CSV
        }))
        .range([0,width])

//Create y Axis
var yAxis = d3.axisLeft()
    .scale(yScale);

//Create X Axis
var xAxis = d3.axisBottom()
    .scale(xScale);

var svgContainer = d3.select("#myDiv").append("svg")
.attr("width", 1000)
.attr("height", 1000);

//Create a rectangle
var myRectangle = svgContainer.selectAll("rect")
.data(data);

//Add Attributes to rectangle
myRectangle.enter()
    .append("rect")
        .attr("x", function(d,i){
            return (50 + (i*(width/dataCount)));
        })
        .attr("y", function(d){
            return yScale(d.sales); // sales from sales csv
        })
        .attr("width", (width/dataCount - gap))
        .attr("height", function(d){
            return height - yScale(d.sales); // sales from sales csv
        })
        .attr("fill", "red");

        svgContainer.append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(45,0)")
            .call(yAxis);

        svgContainer.append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(50,"+ height +")")
            .call(xAxis)
            .selectAll("text")
                .attr("transform","rotate(60)")
                .attr("text-anchor", "start")
                .attr("x","9")
                .attr("y","3");

});

</script>
</html>
```

The above code points to the csv file

```
d3.csv("sales.csv").then(function(data){
    console.log(data);
```

Because I am designing an input form that takes data, I would like to convert the code above to work with two arrays, one for Sales, the other for Month

```
//Sales Data
var SalesArray = [23, 13, 21, 14, 37, 15, 18, 34, 37, 15, 18, 34];
var MonthArray = ["January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December"];
```

In the above code there are references to **d.sales** and **d.month** which refer to the data extracted from the spreadsheet, I'd like to correctly reference those to **SalesArray** & **MonthArray**.

This is all rather new to me. I would appreciate help.

This is as far as I have got with building data to pass to arrays

```
function load_graph(){

num1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("inputbox1").value);
num2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("inputbox2").value);
num3 = parseInt(document.getElementById("inputbox3").value);
num4 = parseInt(document.getElementById("inputbox4").value);
num5 = parseInt(document.getElementById("inputbox5").value);
num6 = parseInt(document.getElementById("inputbox6").value);
num7 = parseInt(document.getElementById("inputbox7").value);
num8 = parseInt(document.getElementById("inputbox8").value);
num9 = parseInt(document.getElementById("inputbox9").value);
num10 = parseInt(document.getElementById("inputbox10").value);
num11 = parseInt(document.getElementById("inputbox11").value);
num12 = parseInt(document.getElementById("inputbox12").value);

var SalesArray = [num1, num2, num3, num4, num5, num6, num7, num8, num9, num10, num11, num12];

var MonthArray = ["January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December"];
```

I hope to paste the working graph code below this to accept values from the arrays rather than the csv file.

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using two arrays `SalesArray` and `MonthArray`, it will be more convenient to use the same data structure as the one found in the CSV file, where each sames figure is explicitly linked with the corresponding Month.

```
data = [
  { month: "January"
    , sales: 200 }
// ...
```

The `data` variable can be populated by iterating through the list of Months, and  looking up  corresponding inputs accordingly, using [`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), as illustrated in the following lines.

```
const months = ["January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December"]

let data = months.map(function(month, i) {
  return {
     month: month
    , sales: +document.getElementById("inputbox" + (i+1)).value
  }
})
```

Assumption: a validation mechanism checks that the sales amounts values entered by the user are actually numbers.

Further recommendations:

- use descriptive names for the input Ids. Rather than `inputbox12`, `decemberSales` is easier to understand. Future you will thank you for making his life easier, whenever he needs to get back to this code after a while.
- avoid capitalizing the first letter of variable names, as these are used for Object constructors by convention.

Edit:

To reply to the question asked in comment.

In order to replace the csv file loading by the data variable,

Just remove the following line:

```
d3.csv("sales.csv").then(function(data){
```

As well as the closing brackets at the end of the script:

```
});
```

In the place where `d3.csv` was called, put the code populating the `data` variable.

Comment: Thank you very much Mehdi for your very thorough answer. I like your solution of putting data = [  { month: "January" , sales: 200 } . I am curious of how I put this snippet of code into the existing code so that this code for the csv is replaced d3.csv("sales.csv").then(function(data){ , and that the code after the csv code works.
    console.log(data);

Comment: I have found link very similar to your solution .. where the graph links back to the array https://jsfiddle.net/matehu/w7h81xz2/

Comment: You're welcome. I just edited the question to explain how to replace `d3.csv` by the `let data =` bit. If the answer provided fixes the problem in your original solution, you may mark it as accepted.

Comment: Mehdi I appreciate the response, I am just trying at the moment to piece your solution together. I am not sure that I pasted in right place or missed something.